# Service discoverability and communication

Tags: ipc, microservices, netflix

I'm creating a microservice architecture.  I'm looking for a way (protocol or other thing) for my services communicate together but with automatic message translation between them.

Example.  I have two kinds of store services, both of them expose their catalogs but with a distinct description format.  I can obviously code an adapter to do the job but the next time, the problem will come back.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome in the schemas restaurants, where a huge collection of soups await you!

From experience, it is not a bad thing at all to interface each data provider (service) with our own normalized and internal schema.

Basically: you have one service which provides its own soup, and you build a microservice (or update an existing one) for the sole purpose of representing the schema in a new format.

No easy solution here, but take a look at pipeline solutions such as **Apache Nifi** or **node-red JS** which could help you to quickly build transformation pipelines. Solutiopns like **JOLT** https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt can help you transform JSON and perform the effort with a comprehensive set of scripts and tools.

Comment: Sorry, answered late... Thank you for your reponse.